# xarray: 2D attribute converted to 1D by to_netcdf

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm trying to save a Dataset with a 2D array as an attribute, as such:

```
attrs = {'objects': np.array([(46.5, -42.5),(4.5, 44),(-69, -69),(-66.5, 73.5)])}
ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars, coords, attrs)
ds.to_netcdf('dataset.nc', engine='netcdf4', format='netCDF4')
```

But loading the file back up shows that the attribute has changed to a 1D array:

```
data = xr.open_dataset('dataset.nc')
print(data.objects)

# array([ 46.5, -42.5,   4.5,  44. , -69. , -69. , -66.5,  73.5])
```

What could be the cause of this? I tried simply passing a list of tuples but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetCDF file format [doesn't support multi-dimensional attributes](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/netcdf/msg10419.html). If you want to store multi-dimensional arrays to netCDF files with xarray, they should to be in `data_vars` or `coords` instead.

But apparently netCDF-Python library will happily write them as vectors, silently discarding the shape information. Xarray or NetCDF4-Python really should raise an error in these cases instead.

If you really want, with the current version of h5netcdf, you can read and write multi-dimensional attributes by specifying `engine='h5netcdf'` in xarray. But beware that this will create non-standard netCDF files that won't be readable with most tools, and I am [considering removing](https://github.com/shoyer/h5netcdf/issues/28) this functionality from h5netcdf in the future.

Comment: The page you linked also says, "This is more restrictive than HDF5, where attributes can be multidimensional". However using `engine='h5netcdf'` raises an error for me, 'NetCDF: Can't open HDF5 attribute'. I guess I'll see about incorporating the information in `data_vars` or `coords`.

Comment: I had a look at incorporating the information in `data_vars` or `coords`, but it's just not really suitable because the dimensions of my `objects` data are not meaningful in relation to the rest of the data. A better option might be to create a completely separate Dataset or other storage for this data, but it's a shame that I'll have to keep track of the two variables.

Comment: Got it, I had to explicitly pass `engine='h5netcdf'` to `open_dataset` in addition to `to_netcdf`. Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to add this information to your answer? Then I can accept it, so that any future searchers might easily find this solution.

Comment: I updated my answer, but I'm still reluctant to recommend that solution.

Comment: Why reluctant? I thought I read that `h5netcdf` was to be the new standard?

Comment: NetCDF is a widely used file format with quite a few tools for working with it: https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/software.html. Most of these tools rely on the NetCDF-C libraries, unlike h5netcdf.